# How to get the nested array value in mongodb

Tags: laravel, mongodb, filter

Need to get collection based on component, Subtype, material value which is inside regions array.

```
"_id":"01"
"pole_num": "1"
"pole_height":"10"
"lat":"39.94142507"
"lon": "-86.07079913"
"image": "_DSC9468.JPG",
"road_accessible": "true",
"regions": {
    0: {
          "Component": "Pole Test",
          "Sub Type": {

          },
          "Material": "Unknown",
          "Condition": {

          },
          "Misc": {

          }
    },
    1: {
          "Component": "TestAnchor",
          "Sub Type": {

          },
          "Material": "Unknown",
          "Condition": {

          },
          "Misc": {

          }
    }
```

---

```
"_id":"02"
"pole_num": "2"
"pole_height":"10"
"lat":"39.94142507"
"lon": "-86.07079913"
"image": "_DSC9468.JPG",
"road_accessible": "true",
"regions": [
    0: {
          "Component": "Pole Test",
          "Sub Type": {

          },
          "Material": "Unknown",
          "Condition": {

          },
          "Misc": {

          }
       },
    1: {
          "Component": "Test Anchor2",
          "Sub Type": {

          },
          "Material": "Unknown",
          "Condition": {

          },
          "Misc": {

          }
      }
```

How to get datas which has "Pole Test" value like given below:

```
"_id":"01"
"pole_num": "1"
"pole_height":"10"
"lat":"39.94142507"
"lon": "-86.07079913"
"image": "_DSC9468.JPG",
"road_accessible": "true",
"regions": {
    0: {
          "Component": "Pole Test",
          "Sub Type": {

          },
          "Material": "Unknown",
          "Condition": {

          },
          "Misc": {

          }
    }
```

and

```
"_id":"02"
"pole_num": "2"
"pole_height":"10"
"lat":"39.94142507"
"lon": "-86.07079913"
"image": "_DSC9468.JPG",
"road_accessible": "true",
"regions": [
    0: {
          "Component": "Pole Test",
          "Sub Type": {

          },
          "Material": "Unknown",
          "Condition": {

          },
          "Misc": {

          }
       }
```

is there any possible mongodb query to work with this.

Comment: Code needs to be cleaned up for display.

Comment: Sure william sorry for this . I am checking with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below. Its a very simple query which can be done using find operator.
Unless there is some sample value provided by you in subtype field.
You can update your question so we can provide better solution

```
db.collection.find({
  "regions.Component": "Pole Test",
  "regions.Material": "Unknown"
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/1K4NXPTllHz

Comment: Hi Sachin, thanks for the answer. I tried your solution but it throws all the array values inside the regions array likse 0:{},1:{}......10:{}

Comment: Ans should be like:
{
  {
    "_id": "02",
    "image": "_DSC9468.JPG",
    "lat": "39.94142507",
    "lon": "-86.07079913",
    "pole_height": "10",
    "pole_num": "2",
    "regions": [
      {
        "Component": "Pole Test",
        "Condition": {},
        "Material": "Unknown",
        "Misc": {},
        "Sub Type": {}
      }
}

Comment: {
      "_id": "03",
      "pole_num": "2",
      "pole_height": "10",
      "lat": "39.94142507",
      "lon": "-86.07079913",
      "image": "_DSC9468.JPG",
      "road_accessible": "true",
      "regions": {
        {
          "Component": "Pole Nest",
          "Sub Type": {},
          "Material": "Unknown",
          "Condition": {},
          "Misc": {}
        },
      }
    } 
previous comment value and this comment value.

Comment: for me the number 0 and 1 in the sample data is wrong. it doesn't say its a valid json. Unless i am doing anything wrong. Can you put a valid json which can easily be validated on http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: {"_id":{"$oid":"5d72ccxxxxxxxx6"},"pole_num":{"$numberInt":"2"},"pole_height":{"$numberInt":"10"},"lat":{"$numberDouble":"00.0000"},"lon":{"$numberDouble":"-00.0000"},"image":"_DSC9468.JPG","road_accessible":"true","regions":[{"Component":"Test Xiomi","Sub Type":{},"Material":"Unknown","Condition":{},"Misc":{}},{"Component":"Test Nokia","Sub Type":{"Test 1100":true,"Test 6110":true,"Test smart":true},"Material":"Ceramic","Condition":{},"Misc":{}},{"Component":"Test Xiomi","Sub Type":{},"Material":"Unknown","Condition":{},"Misc":{}}]}

Comment: If above is the json then the answer should work. however that is a sample data and actual implementation will vary. The idea is to give you a hint on how you should proceed ahead with query.